# Warning "Variable is not a factor" using predict for One-Hot encoding using caret

Tags: r, warnings, r-caret, one-hot-encoding

I'm following [this tutorial](https://www.machinelearningplus.com/machine-learning/caret-package/) to learn the very basics of the caret package in R and machine learning.

I get a warning message I don't understand, and I don't know if it's a problem. This happens both when I apply the tutorial steps to my own data and when I follow the tutorial.

```
orange <- read.csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/selva86/datasets/master/orange_juice_withmissing.csv')
trainRowNumbers <- createDataPartition(orange$Purchase, p=0.8, list=FALSE)

# Step 2: Create the training  dataset
trainData <- orange[trainRowNumbers,]

# Step 3: Create the test dataset
testData <- orange[-trainRowNumbers,]

#Impute
preProcess_missingdata_model <- preProcess(trainData, method='knnImpute')
preProcess_missingdata_model
library(RANN)  # required for knnInpute
trainData <- predict(preProcess_missingdata_model, newdata = trainData)

#One-hot encoding
dummies_model <- dummyVars(Purchase ~ ., data=trainData)
trainData_mat <- predict(dummies_model, newdata = trainData)
```

I get:
Warning message:
In model.frame.default(Terms, newdata, na.action = na.action, xlev = object$lvls) :
  variable 'Purchase' is not a factor

But:

```
is.factor(trainData$Purchase)
[1] TRUE
```

I have two questions:

1. What is going on?
2. Is this important?
3. (For extra points) why are R warning/error messages so bad and uninformative?

Comment: Unclear from a quick look.  If you want to dive into the source code try `print(caret:::predict.dummyVars)` and then `print(model.frame.default)` or in Rstudio `View(caret:::predict.dummyVars)` and then `View(model.frame.default)`

Comment: I am getting the same issue, yet when I call `print(class(df$column_name))` I get "factor", strange behavior and I don't seem to see why when looking at `View(model.frame.defualt)`

Answer (score 0):

You can easily fix it by removing the label before the ~.

In this case, your code would look like:

```
#One-hot encoding
dummies_model <- dummyVars(~ ., data=trainData)
trainData_mat <- predict(dummies_model, newdata = trainData)
```

Answer (score 0):

I just found this question because I had the same problem in the tutorial. In the end my solution for the tutorial is to do it like this:

```
dummies_model <- dummyVars(~ ., data = trainData[, names(trainData) != "Purchase"])
```

This way you exclude the `purchase` column that would otherwise be also splitted into dummy variables. With my solution you can just go on with the tutorial and don't get any warning.